# UserWarning: Encountered more than 100 detections in a single image

Tags: pytorch, torchvision, retinanet, user-warning

I am currently using the retinanet model to identify cells in clinical images. When training the model I get the following error:

```
EPOCH 1 of 50 
Training Loss: 1.0731: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 100/100 [41:57<00:00, 25.17s/it]
Validating
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 3/3 [00:40<00:00, 13.61s/it]
C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\torchmetrics\utilities\prints.py:42: UserWarning: Encountered more than 100 detections in a single image. 
This means that certain detections with the lowest scores will be ignored, that may have an undesirable impact on performance. 
Please consider adjusting the `max_detection_threshold` to suit your use case. To disable this warning, set attribute class `warn_on_many_detections=False`, after initializing the metric.
  warnings.warn(*args, **kwargs)  # noqa: B028
```

The model continues with the following periods but I would like to know what caused this error and how I could correct it.
The code associated with the training is the following:

```
### train.py
def train(train_data_loader, model):
    print('Training')
    model.train()
    
     # initialize tqdm progress bar
    prog_bar = tqdm(train_data_loader, total=len(train_data_loader))
    
    for i, data in enumerate(prog_bar):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        images, targets = data
        
        images = list(image.to(DEVICE) for image in images)
        targets = [{k: v.to(DEVICE) for k, v in t.items()} for t in targets]
        loss_dict = model(images, targets)

        losses = sum(loss for loss in loss_dict.values())
        loss_value = losses.item()

        train_loss_hist.send(loss_value)

        losses.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    
        # update the loss value beside the progress bar for each iteration
        prog_bar.set_description(desc=f"Loss: {loss_value:.4f}")
    return loss_value
def validate(valid_data_loader, model):
    print('Validating')
    model.eval()
    
    # Initialize tqdm progress bar.
    prog_bar = tqdm(valid_data_loader, total=len(valid_data_loader))
    target = []
    preds = []
    for i, data in enumerate(prog_bar):
        images, targets = data
        images = list(image.to(DEVICE) for image in images)
        targets = [{k: v.to(DEVICE) for k, v in t.items()} for t in targets]
        with torch.no_grad():
            outputs = model(images, targets)

        # For mAP calculation using Torchmetrics.
        #####################################
        for i in range(len(images)):
            true_dict = dict()
            preds_dict = dict()
            true_dict['boxes'] = targets[i]['boxes'].detach().cpu()
            true_dict['labels'] = targets[i]['labels'].detach().cpu()
            preds_dict['boxes'] = outputs[i]['boxes'].detach().cpu()
            preds_dict['scores'] = outputs[i]['scores'].detach().cpu()
            preds_dict['labels'] = outputs[i]['labels'].detach().cpu()
            preds.append(preds_dict)
            target.append(true_dict)
        #####################################

    metric.reset()
    metric.update(preds, target)
    metric_summary = metric.compute()
    return metric_summary

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.makedirs('outputs', exist_ok=True)
    train_dataset = create_train_dataset(TRAIN_DIR)
    valid_dataset = create_valid_dataset(VALID_DIR)
    train_loader = create_train_loader(train_dataset, NUM_WORKERS)
    valid_loader = create_valid_loader(valid_dataset, NUM_WORKERS)
    print(f"Number of training samples: {len(train_dataset)}")
    print(f"Number of validation samples: {len(valid_dataset)}\n")

    # Initialize the model and move to the computation device.
    model = create_model(num_classes=NUM_CLASSES)
    model = model.to(DEVICE)
    print(model)
    # Total parameters and trainable parameters.
    total_params = sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters())
    print(f"{total_params:,} total parameters.")
    total_trainable_params = sum(
        p.numel() for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad)
    print(f"{total_trainable_params:,} training parameters.")
    params = [p for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad]
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(params, lr=0.001, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    scheduler = StepLR(
        optimizer=optimizer, step_size=15, gamma=0.1, verbose=True
    )

    # To monitor training loss
    train_loss_hist = Averager()
    # To store training loss and mAP values.
    train_loss_list = []
    map_50_list = []
    map_list = []

    # Mame to save the trained model with.
    MODEL_NAME = 'model'

    # Whether to show transformed images from data loader or not.
    if VISUALIZE_TRANSFORMED_IMAGES:
        from custom_utils import show_tranformed_image
        show_tranformed_image(train_loader)

    # To save best model.
    save_best_model = SaveBestModel()

    metric = MeanAveragePrecision()

    # Training loop.
    for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
        print(f"\nEPOCH {epoch+1} of {NUM_EPOCHS}")

        # Reset the training loss histories for the current epoch.
        train_loss_hist.reset()

        # Start timer and carry out training and validation.
        start = time.time()
        train_loss = train(train_loader, model)
        metric_summary = validate(valid_loader, model)
        print(f"Epoch #{epoch+1} train loss: {train_loss_hist.value:.3f}")   
        print(f"Epoch #{epoch+1} mAP: {metric_summary['map']*100}")   
        end = time.time()
        print(f"Took {((end - start) / 60):.3f} minutes for epoch {epoch}")

        train_loss_list.append(train_loss)
        map_50_list.append(metric_summary['map_50'])
        map_list.append(metric_summary['map'])

        # save the best model till now.
        save_best_model(
            model, float(metric_summary['map']), epoch, 'outputs'
        )
        # Save the current epoch model.
        save_model(epoch, model, optimizer)

        # Save loss plot.
        save_loss_plot(OUT_DIR, train_loss_list)

        # Save mAP plot.
        save_mAP(OUT_DIR, map_50_list, map_list)
        # scheduler.step()
```

I tried looking for how to modify the "max detection threshold" value but I can't find it.

Comment: I don't think this is something to be concerned about, this is saying that while validating the model detected a lot of objects in a single image. The model should be able to correct itself over the iterations. If you don't get the desired performance on the test set, consider finetuning the model, try different loss functions, optimizer etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `torchmetrics` documentation:

> max_detection_thresholds (Optional[List[int]]) – Thresholds on max
> detections per image. If set to None will use thresholds [1, 10, 100].
> Else, please provide a list of ints.

Basically, for faster evaluation purposes, `torchmetrics` has implemented a quick and dirty rule where they select only the detection outputs with the `max_detection_thresholds` highest confidence scores. If you had, say, hundreds of thousands of anchor boxes in your model and thus many many outputs this may save significant time, but in most cases is probably negligible relative to the loss backprop step.

Do note that this accuracy computation differs from the loss function. The loss is part of the computation graph and is backpropogated, the accuracy computation is not. It does not numerically affect training at all, only the information you see about the model's performance.

If you want to raise the theshold you can initialize the `MeanAveragePrecision` module with the keyword argument `max_detection_thresholds` per their [documentation](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/detection/mean_average_precision.html). If you don't care (it's just for eval purposes, not training) you can supress the warning with:

```
import warnings 
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```